# Parallel.For: Is it safe to lock the value?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing

Im trying to figure out the output of this code:

```
Dictionary<int, MyRequest> request = new Dictionary<int, MyRequest>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
  request.Add(i, new MyRequest() { Name = i.ToString() });
}

var ids = request.Keys.ToList();

Parallel.For(0, ids.Count, (t) =>
{
  var id = ids[t];
  var b = request[id];

  lock (b)
  {
    if (b.Name == 4.ToString())
    {
      Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(b.Name);
  }
});

Console.WriteLine("done");
Console.Read();
```

**output:**

```
789
800
875
.
.
.
4
5
6
7
done
```

MyRequest is just a dummy class used for demonstration (it is not doing anything but holding values).  Is my lock blocking the execution or are  the last 4 being put on their own thread?

This is a .NET 4.0 demo.

**UPDATE**
Ok I did figure out they were on teh same thread, but i would still like to know if the lock does anything to block execution.  I cant imagine it does.

Comment: What? Are you talking about the values being sequential? You may try printing the thread id alongside the number.

Comment: Useless nitpick: `4.ToString()` is actually longer that `"4"`.

Comment: No, I dont care about sequence.  I just thought it was odd that the output for the last 4 was consistent, as if they were all on the same thread affected by timer.

Comment: It should be safe, you can lock in any object which is referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `ids` does not contain duplicates, that lock won't block anything. But if there are duplicates in `ids`, then yes, there might be contention at the lock, as different threads fight for access to the same request.

Comment: Even if (and especially if) `MyRequest` was a value type, it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: If i used Parallel.Foreach and iterated request.Values, and locked the passed value, does that lock out the enumerator?

Comment: @Mike_G No. Enumerators are distinct from the object they point to. Locking the pointed object won't lock the enumerator.

Answer (score 2):

Your `lock` will only be blocking execution if the ids line up such that you retrieve the same request more than once. Since different names are being printed each time, that shouldn't be a concern.

Answer (score 1):

`Parallel.For` uses a thread pool to process your loop. As soon as one of its threads is free, it assigns it to the next element. This is non-deterministic, because you don't know how many threads there are in the pool, and you don't control the CPU time given to each thread. This means that some threads may finish sooner or later than you would "naturally" expect.

Your lock isn't doing anything. A lock blocks delimits sections of code that attempt to use the same object. In your case, you're not ever using the same object twice in the loop. The fact that the last IDs processed seem consistent is probably purely coincidental.

Comment: Thanks zneak.  This demo is really just a mockup of an enumerable that i would like to use the Parallel library for in order to avoid a bottle neck in processing.  The lock may look like its not doing anything here, but it syncs other threads in the program.  My main concern was for some reason blocking the enumeration by locking the value.

Comment: @Mike_G In this case, it will block one thread from the pool, but the rest will keep going fine and it won't lock up the whole enumeration (unless all the threads in the pool get blocked that way).